# Pokémon Go Friends Limit?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a limit to the number of friends one can add in Pokémon Go? I have been adding people as friends in a lot of different places and I want to make sure I don't run out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this Pokémon Go support post](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001509668-Friend-List-Friendship-Levels), you can have up to 200 friends at a time. That limit is rather large, so you shouldn't worry about it for a while anyway.